# Rails server is started but localhost:3000 shows error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just installed Ruby on Rails package that found in http://rubyinstaller.org/ (This is my first attempt to set up the ruby on rails workstation in my xp sp3 system.). The installation process went perfectly without any errors. I started the server using it's console. Server is started but **http://localhost:3000** shows an error page (page not found). 
I have following display in the console.Am i missing anything?

```
#Rails Environment Configuration.

---
git:
  user.name:  XYZ
  user.email: xyzuser
  version:    git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1

ruby:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
  version:    ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]

rails:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails.bat
  version:    Rails 3.2.13

ssh:
  public_key_location: C:\Documents and Settings\xyz/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  public_key_contents: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArYKMRvMHxKJ2R//5viqQp
D4IQhVcKZhhbfvZGzDOXF1M//pewAQDK2x9y8T8irvatgmDMCYB5L2uZiyXwG3gPm6Bfw44mCHhNP8xN
bT2OSDnvIoZcFVfmQExZmwWcSNqm0NionObUV+IFKvfjg9bOPl4GBUqSXSTlUmAn/wQq0c/m+GoJwDlI
dV/h69dq4tHYwpCMFUZ9k4LqR4VICktV5Fi1VQA14u4Y9kOWAAyAfzeXnOzcpkbYxgjbCvAf20gM6lSL
9NvNsLuzI5yLxhI5wAmZbK+11zgNmx019tbv1uHvZRV2Z53aWpErtuvipAieQ977U4kYQPMyFf8g8BKd
Q== XYZ<xyzuser>




C:\Sites>
```

And the console output when the server is started is:

```
C:\Sites>rails s
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
.exe
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a files
ystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a fil
esystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options:
mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3
/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing t
o your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing t
o Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on
 Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.

C:\Sites>
```

Comment: Could you please add the console output you see when starying rails

Comment: yes, i have posted it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone. Finally I got it worked. The problem was the **Gemfile** in my **test_app** folder. I commented on the line **gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'** and i got it worked. Hopefully it will work further as well and let me move on.

Comment: You might still need this Gem (or you run into problems with other gems of this Gemfile), then you can automatically install these gems with a programm called bundler. This should be already be installed with your rails installation, see http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_install.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `cd` in the directory of the created rails project, then `rails s` should work fine.

This means also, that the server has not started yet. Please read carefully the output of the console commands, most of the time they tell you what they do, or why they don't work as expected.

Comment: Yes I created a rails project as well...it looks like this **C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app**

Comment: Then do `cd railsbridge\test_app` and afterwars `rails s`, then the server will run.

Comment: PS: A running server will produce an console output like `=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000` and `>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop` - if you read something like this, you can try in the browser ;)

Comment: The output is `C:\Sites>cd railsbridge\test_app

C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>rails s
←[31mCould not find gem 'uglifier (>= 1.0.3) x86-mingw32' in the gems available
on this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>`

Answer (score 0):

Server is not started. You need to navigate to your rails app folder, install needed gems and start the server:

```
cd <your app folder>
bundle install
rails s
```

Comment: I am confused with the command lines you have mentioned. Could you please write them down here?

Comment: Error : `C:\Sites>cd railsbridge

C:\Sites\railsbridge>cd test_app

C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>rails s
←[31mCould not find gem 'uglifier (>= 1.0.3) x86-mingw32' in the gems available
on this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>`

Comment: You need to install needed gems. Run `bundle install` and after it completes successfully run `rails s`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a new rails project. I think that C:/Sites is not your rails project directory.

```
rails new test_app
```

It will create a rails project in your directory. than go to  cd test_app. and try to start your server. 
Hope it will work.